# (How) can I split a long string in a maven property without having newline characters in the property value?

Tags: java, maven

I tried it with backslash-escaping the newline, like this:

```
  <my.property>MIICQDCCAakCBEeNB0swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEEBQAwZz\
ELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNh</my.property>
```

or this:

```
  <my.property>\
MIICQDCCAakCBEeNB0swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEEBQ\
AwZzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNh\
</my.property>
```

But it didn't work, I get the backslash and the newline in the property value. Is it possible to get the value of "my.property" be this:

```
MIICQDCCAakCBEeNB0swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEEBQAwZzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNh
```

without having to write the whole String on one line?

Comment: What is the problem having that string in one line?

Comment: I dont think this eclipse specific question.

Comment: @khmarbaise it's just an example, we actually have a long comma separated list of strings which would be much more maintainable if we could split it over multiple lines - unfortunately we cannot adjust the parser that reads this value

Comment: @Matthias i wasn't sure but you're probably right, i removed the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the string into multiple properties and use all into one final property like below. It is a hack but it works.

```
<Properties>
    <p1>string1</p1>
    <p2>string2</p2>
    <p3>string3</p3>
    <p>${p1}${p2}${p3}</p>
</Properties>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way because the Plexus XML reader does not support that type of continuation you are used from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

try using shift+enter if getting the values to span across multiple lines is your only aim.

Comment: Shift-Enter is an editor command. It typically enters a character that is interpreted as a line break _in that editor_. What's asked for is a way to have a character interpreted as a line break _by Maven_, and Shift-Enter will not help in the least for that.